# issue with float value printing in cpp

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include<bits/stdc++.h> 
using namespace std;
int solve(int t){
    float ans = static_cast<float>(320)/100;
    cout<<fixed<<setprecision(2)<<ans;
}
int main(){
    int t=320;
    cout<<solve(t);
    return 0;
}
```

output:3.204745728

how should I get output as 3.20

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h

Comment: You are invoking undefined behavior by not returning a value in `int solve()`, change to `void solve(int t)` and call it in `main` as `solve(t)`;

Comment: "*how should I get output as 3.20*" Comment out the `cout` line in `main`. This will also remove the undefined behavior due to using the return value of `solve`, which `solve` forgot to return.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude FWIW this looks to be one of the rarer cases which is *not* a duplicate of the canonical question.

Comment: @dxiv True, now that I see it again. But I'll bet there's some nice duplicate for the real issue as well. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `cout` twice, when you only want to output one thing. You are also outputting the return value of `solve` when you don't return anything from `solve`, this explains the extra digits that you see.

Either do the `cout` in `solve` or do it in `main`, don't do it in both places.

First way

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void solve(int t){
    float ans = static_cast<float>(320)/100;
    cout<<fixed<<setprecision(2)<<ans; // print the answer
}
int main(){
    int t=320;
    solve(t);
    return 0;
}
```

Second way

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
float solve(int t){
    float ans = static_cast<float>(320)/100;
    return ans;                        // return the answer
}
int main(){
    int t=320;
    cout<<fixed<<setprecision(2)<<solve(t);
    return 0;
}
```

Another issue with your code is that you are passing the parameter `320` to `solve`, but you aren't using it there. You might want to change that

```
float ans = static_cast<float>(t)/100;
```

It's quite common for beginners to get confused between *returning* a value from a function, and *printing* a value in a function, but these are quite different things. The first code above prints the value in the function, the  second code above returns the value from the function (and prints it in `main`).